# Microsoft Band SDK on Windows Phone 10

Tags: c#, windows-phone, microsoft-band

Folks, most users seem to have issues running one of our apps on Windows Phone 10, as the OS needs to "prompt" for use of the Band on first run. I don't see any way to programmatically request permission, and the app fails to connect unless they remove their pairing completely, remove the app, re-add the pairing, and reinstall the app. Then (and only then) will the OS prompt for use of the Band, and then it works.

Is this by design? How do I programmatically prompt for permission, and why does the WP10 OS not just prompt instead of failing? Is there something additional I need in the manifest for WP10 more than WP8.1?

Thoughts?

Comment: To clarify, we have a popular MICROSOFT BAND app that experiences these issue when used on Windows Phone 10. :)